# What's the best way to append html just once?

Tags: jquery, append, toggle

I want to open a Div and append the Facebook comments box when I click on a "Show comments" link. But I want to append the FB-Comments just once, and then just use the link to toggle that Div.

I was trying something like this but it just appends it every time I click on the link, of course...

http://jsfiddle.net/4LnzD/

Thanks!!

**UPDATE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/4LnzD/4/

Now it's working great, but if someone knows a most efficient way to do it, you're welcome!

Comment: why use append rather than toggling visibility?

Comment: @deltree I think it's better not to load ALL (I have a lot of entries with individual comments) the facebook comments boxes. I just want to load on click...

Comment: then load them via AJAX, and the div should still be visible or invisible based on the toggle, not created by the AJAX call

Comment: @deltree And how could I load them via AJAX? (It's an HTML5 code from Facebook)

Comment: I'd have to know where your uid comes from in order to answer that

Comment: The ID is my own entry Id on my site. And the URL to that particular post is mysite.com/uid. So, the facebook comments use that UID to load. Like... data-href="http://mysite.com/uid"... I don't load the comments from my own DB, so I just append the Facebook code with that UID.

Comment: @deltree Yes, I load a post with a unique ID tied to the Facebook comments, so the IDs are predefined... If I understand correctly what you're asking... mmhh

Comment: alright, I have to run, but I'll post an answer to this tonight

Comment: looks like you're settled with a good enough answer.  I don't have the time to post for any minor improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class name to the target element after adding the content. Check for the existence of the class name before adding it a second time.

1) add the class

```
$('#target').addClass("done")
```

2) check for the class

```
if($('#target').hasClass("done")) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: I tried using ".hasClass" but I couldn't do it. Unfortunately I'm not a pro with jQuery :(

Comment: I'm doing this but I thinks I'm doing it wrong... $('#fb_comentarios_' + uid).addClass("done")
 if($('#fb_comentarios_').hasClass("done")) {
  $('#fb_comentarios_' + uid).toggle();
 } else {
 $('#fb_comentarios_' + uid).append(commentBox);
 }

Comment: You are missing the "+ uid" in your IF statement.

Comment: Ups, I didn't noticed... However, I'm still doing something wrong... The .append on my else statement is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/4LnzD/3/

Comment: I was doing the .addClass before the IF, now it's working! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the comments div already exists in the DOM, if it doesn't then append:

```
if( ! $('#fb_comments_' + uid).children(".fb-comments").length ){
  $('#fb_comments_' + uid).append(commentBox);
}

$('#fb_comments_' + uid).toggle();
```

.length will return the number of instances of elements that match that selector in the DOM. As 0 is equivalent to false in javascript, we can treat it as a boolean in the conditional.

Comment: This works but if I click on the link before all the page is loaded it doesn't do anything. Thats odd...

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(document).load( function() {
    //Load comments section here
    $('.fb_comments').hide(); 
})
```

This will create the comments, but then hide them.  Then create the button, and `onClick` (or bind a `.click()`) call this:

```
$('.fb_comments').toggle();
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want to load all the facebook comments when I load the page, but just when I click on the "show comments" link...

Comment: @Santiago why not load them in the background on document load?  Why make your user wait after they click?

Comment: @ehudokai Maybe that would be better. The thing is that I use a "load more" like twitter, and I don't know if loading 50 or more facebook comments boxes would be the best